# Почему функциональное программирование не так часто применяется для написания игр?

Tags: javascript, разработка-игр

Почему функциональное программирование не так часто применяется для написания игр?

Comment: Для чего функциональное программирование применяется часто? Не многие даже знают что это такое.

Comment: Отладка, многопоточность, например.

Comment: С отладкой и так порядок, а многопоточность не на ГП в играх нужна очень редко.

Comment: Они достаточно высокоуровневые, понятны и просты.

Comment: Потому, что большинство примеров и технологий используют исторически сложившийся императивный стиль, к которому все привыкли. Поэтому для функционального программирования придется привыкнуть к обоим стилям, переводить существующие примеры на ФП, найти хорошие инструменты поддерживающие ФП и найти сообщество, которое еще со всем этим сможет помочь. Слишком много условия для перехода на ФП и слишком мало отдачи от подобных шагов.

Comment: Я видел несколько проектов написанных таким образом на js, мне кажется что дай волю, многие бы предпочли более простой и понятный в общении с компьютером способ не прибегая к сложным конструкциям. Или я не вижу чего-то помимо не популярности таких решений?

Comment: Для меня этот вопрос выглядит как "Почему `switch .. case` не так часто применяется для написания игр, как `if .. else`?". Просто потому, что в целом функциональное программирование вообще применяется реже, не везде и не является панацеей.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**tl;dr: он непопулярен, специалистов тяжело найти, материалов мало.**

---

Причин несколько, в основном **исторические** и **временные**.

Исторически императивный стиль начал применяться раньше, поскольку от программ в этом стиле до машинопонятного представления *меньше преобразований*. Посему, основная доля игр писалась именно в этом стиле. Область развивалась, обретала архитектуру, строясь на достижениях предшественников, которые функциональный  стиль **не** использовали, как правило.

Не без исключений, конечно. **Abuse** (1995) и некоторые игры *Naughty Dog* написаны с большой долей на [лиспах](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%9B%D0%B8%D1%81%D0%BF). Насколько там используется "труъ" функциональщина, под вопросом, но если нет, непонятно, зачем вообще было брать лисп, верно?

---

Сейчас использование функционального программирования **во всей индустрии разработки программного обеспечения** (в т. ч. игр) достаточно редкое явление. "Большой игрострой" отказывается от него, потому что **специалисты дорого стоят**: с Naughty Dog это и прозошло, когда их выкупили Sony, их вынудили от лиспа отказаться, мол, "вы иначе с нашими не сработаетесь". То же самое относится и к игрокам-мододелам — "функциональщиков" среди них очень мало.

Во многом это опирается на то, *как в наше время становятся программистами*. Ведь не секрет, что многие стали программистами из желания заниматься разработкой игр (я сам из таких), а при наличии желания начинаешь самостоятельно искать материалы. И попадаются те материалы, которых в округе больше всего. И обычно они **не** про функциональное программирование.

Функциональное программирование это круто, но его "никто не применяет на практике", потому что "нет специалистов" (которых выгодно нанять), а они не появляются, потому что на них нет спроса. **Выглядит ситуация, как заколдованный круг,** который можно разорвать, потихоньку обучая специалистов работать в функциональном стиле, для чего нужны соответствующие технологии, которые можно внедрять постепенно (выработать мотив), а затем учебные материалы (чтобы мотив поддержать).

---

Но если забыть обо всём этом, надо понимать, что функциональщина — не серебряная пуля, которая может всё. И уместна она далеко не везде. Она прекрасна для описания строгой логики **небольшого объёма**, где производительность не будет сильно парить.

Производительность в основном убивают **аллокации**, которые для функционального стиля очень типичны из-за предпочтения *персистентных структур данных*, если их будет немного, проблем не будет.

*Ситуация может измениться, если кто-то реализует мощный встраиваемый функциональный язык, оптимизирующий работу с памятью. Теоретически это может быть предсказание того, где она будет освобождаться и максимальное переиспользование того, что уже есть, простыми генерируемыми компилятором алгоритмами прямо на месте.*

Чтобы игра работала на 60 кадрах в секунду, на каждый кадр есть всего около 16 миллисекунд, **поэтому основу игры лучше писать на том, что хорошо проработано и работает шустро**: если оно предсказуемо, то с кодом в функциональном стиле прекрасно сработается, и производительность огорчать не будет. "Functional core, imperative shell" ([Gary Bernhardt, Boundaries](https://www.destroyallsoftware.com/talks/boundaries))

<sub>В работе эту комбинацию можно увидеть, например, в `re-natal`, шустром React Native, соединённом с функциональным ClojureScript. Но популярность даже самого React Native пока не заоблачная, люди не верят, что запихивание в приложение целого JS-рантайма принесёт ему пользу.</sub>

---

#### Несколько интересных докладов с ClojureTV по теме:

- [Доклад о создании адвенчуры на Clojure](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=lql2yFXzKUs) (с каверзными вопросами в конце)
- [JavaFX + Clojure для инструментов разработки игр](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ajX09xQ_UEg)
- [Реализация почти традиционного ECS в ClojureScript](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=V1Eu9vZaDYw)

Comment: Да, те проекты о которых я писал ранее, скорее всего были написаны на clojure, и да, все же как альтернатива lua он показался мне неплохим вариантом.

Comment: А я заминусую так как функциональное программирование и процедурное программирование разные в корне разные вещи.

Comment: @Naumov окей, укажите, где я их перепутал, потому что слова "процедурное" у меня в ответе нет вообще.

Comment: А можете подтвердить свои слова объяснив чем является let, const, if, while в контексте.. ну естественно в контексте фп? А то складывается впечатление, что Вы просто гугл-бот который где-то что-то слушал и что-то откуда-то скопировал..

Comment: @vas а какое вам дело до меня, по ответу вопросы будут? :) Но если вы так просите, то: (а) связывание значения с названием на уровне языка, (б) недоразумение императивного мира где значения можно менять, (в) функция от трёх переменных с ленивым вычислением и (г) почти ненужная вещь при наличии хвостовой рекурсии.

Comment: @D-side, ну вот я приблизительно так и думал. В фп нет места всему тому что я перечислил, это вне фп. А то что все сейчас обсуждают как mainstream, это не фп, это больше процедуры.

Comment: @vas (а) и (в) имеют непосредственное отношение к ФП, и я вам час назад объяснил, какое :) Возможно, вы имели в виду конструкции `if` и `let` из какого-то конкретного языка, в этом случае язык стоило указать. Контекст важен.

Comment: @D-side, а Вы когда отвечали не смотрели чтоль про какой язык идет речь? Вопрос был о js, я и говорю о js. И вот в контексте js никому нет места в фп. То есть то что сейчас 99% называют фп, это не фп. блин, не получается ссылку кинуть, слишком большая. 
> Как уже́ говорилось, использование локальных переменных представляет собой побочный эффект, поэтому оно недопустимо в функциональных языках.

Comment: @vas а я говорю не про JS, вопрос куда более общий, с JS автор его никак не связал :) И автора ответ, как видите, устроил. JS действительно к ФП отношения не имеет почти никакого. И про локальные переменные, заметьте, я ничего не сказал, это вы сами придумали. Связывание это не переменная, оно задаётся в момент создания и далее существует только для чтения. С локальными переменными в теории можно обращаться так же, это черта функционального стиля, но поскольку язык позволяет их менять, опереться на это нельзя.

Comment: @D-side, как же он его не связал, если один единственный тег который был на момент Вашего ответа, был javascript...? Я не знаю что такое связывание, если это let, то что это как не "контекстная переменная". У неё почти идентичное поведение, кроме всплытия и.. и все. Она точно так же идет вниз по скопе, как и обычная. А то что объявляют по другому, так это пофигу как её назвали, суть остается та же. И это не меняет концепцию фп, которая противоречит хранению состояния даже локально.

Comment: @vas это уже вопрос к автору, зачем он упомянул JS и почему принял мой ответ, несмотря на отсутствие упоминаний о нём. А `let` я понимаю в значении, используемом в Haskell и Clojure: в них попытка связать другое значение с уже связанным именем может быть лишь при входе в новую область видимости (рекурсивный вызов, `let`-выражение или чего ещё), а при её покидании значение "вернётся обратно" (будет действовать более ранее связывание), состояние хранить в ней не получится. В JS же это всего лишь локальная переменная с парой дополнительных правил. Мы с вами просто о разных вещах говорим.